# How can i cover footer image the whole screen with CSS

Tags: html, css

I can't get my footer image to strech the entire screen. The right side is fine but the left wont cover the entire gap. Before anything else. due to the way the website is set up. I cannot change anything from the HTML code beyond whatever that is in the `footerContainer` tag. That is just how the backend is set up for the client. I've tried using a `background` and `x-repeat`, but, backgrounds dont strech beyond the DIV itself.

`Footer` is basically the white text inside the footer `background`.

Comment: Can you post code examples to provide more guidance to the help you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following two properties to the `.background` class in the CSS.

```
left: 0px;
right: 100%;
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Note that as jchapa and Sam Pellino say below, absolute styling isn't ideal - even if it is an effective fix in this case.

Also, I had a brain fart and wrote the wrong thing for `right`. It should be `100%`. Have update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the footer `div`'s css `left` property to 0:

```
left: 0;
```

Comment: Absolute styles aren't quite as ideal as a more fluid layout, although this will fix the problem. . .

Comment: Yes, as @jchapa said, try to avoid using Absolute styling when possible. It can be unreliable. But since you can not edit your HTML, this is a quick fix to your problem.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick reply, I changed the 'left' value to 0 but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Put your footer outside the `<div id="frame">...</div>`. You may need to tweak other CSS to accomodate for that.